# If statement inside for loop in VBA does not work

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I have such a sheet:

```
G                M              N           O
Warrant/Rights                              08-06-2020
NA          
Share                           1   
Share           
Share                           1   
Share            4,5                        15-02-2026
Share                                       06-01-2026
Share            4                          15-03-2023
Share                                       30-09-2027
```

Then I try to compare the `G` column by type `Share` with the column `O` by date. In this way, if in the column `O` is the percentage of not enough entered dates, the program is to clear all cells from `M to O` after the type `Share`. I have something like this:

```
Sub aaa()
    x1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("G2:G" & rows.Count), "Share")
    y1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("G2:G" & rows.Count), "Share", Range("O2:O" & rows.Count), "")
    If x1 > 0 Then
        z1 = (y1 / x1) * 100
        Dim LR24 As Long, i24 As Long
        LR24 = Range("G" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i24 = LR24 To 1 Step -1
            If (Range("G" & i24).Value = "Share" And z1 < 90) Then Range("M" & i24 & ":O" & i24).Clear
        Next i24
    End If
End Sub
```

After removing the condition `If x1> 0 Then` everything works, but I have to put it in order to protect myself from division by 0. Do you have an idea why it does not work?

Comment: if `x1=0` then you don't want to do *any* of that block of code... or are you only trying to prevent the division-by-zero error?

Comment: I only trying to prevent the division-by-zero error.

Comment: I did not know this, I will try.

Comment: Everything works beautiful, thanks a lot :) Although I also made a different attempt and exchanged `For i24 = LR24 To 1 Step -1` on `For i24 = 1 To LR24` and I do not know why, but it also worked. But I will stay with you because it simplifies the code.

Comment: This is good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove your `If...End If` statement and instead replace your z1=... line with:

```
z1 = IIf(x1 = "", 0, (y1 / x1) * 100)
```

It's untested so I don't know how it will affect the rest of your code, but you won't get the Div/0 error on that line.

Instead of an `If`, it uses the `Iif` function (short for Inline If or Immediate If, depending on who you ask).

There's no reason you couldn't also use a standard `If..Then` statement in the same way, located only around the one line instead of preventing execution of a section of code.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`IIf` Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/iif-function)
- Wikipedia : [**IIf**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf)
- Panopticon : [***"IIF, a True Ternary Operator and Backwards Compatibility"***](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2006/12/29/iif-a-true-ternary-operator-and-backwards-compatibility/)